# actionSheet:didDismissWithButtonIndex: is deprecated in iOS 8.3. What is the new method I have to use now?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiactionsheet, dismiss

These are deprecated, but I don't find the solution to improve it :

```
 [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Take Photo", nil) style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(__unused UIAlertAction *action)
                          {
                              [self actionSheet:nil didDismissWithButtonIndex:0];
                          }]];
```

And:

```
  [[[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", nil) destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"Take Photo", nil), NSLocalizedString(@"Photo Library", nil), nil] showInView:controller.view];
```

Finally:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(__unused UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    UIImagePickerControllerSourceType sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    switch (buttonIndex)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            break;
        }
        case 1:
```

Many thanks.

Comment: ⌘-click on `UIActionSheet`. There you will find the suggestion how to replace it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UIAlerController` as `UIActionSheet` is deprecated after `iOS` 8.3.

Please have look at below code for your reference.

```
UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController
                                alertControllerWithTitle:nil      //  Must be "nil", otherwise a blank title area will appear above our two buttons
                                message:nil
                                preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

UIAlertAction* button0 = [UIAlertAction
                              actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                              style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                              handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                              {
                                  //  UIAlertController will automatically dismiss the view
                              }];

UIAlertAction* button1 = [UIAlertAction
                              actionWithTitle:@"Camera"
                              style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive
                              handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                              {
//  The user tapped on "Camera"
}];

UIAlertAction* button2 = [UIAlertAction
                              actionWithTitle:@"Photo Library"
                              style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive
                              handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                              {
//  The user tapped on "Camera"
}];

[alert addAction:button0];
[alert addAction:button1];
[alert addAction:button2];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Hope t his will guide you to get into `UIAlterController` in replace of `UIActionSheet`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From Apple's [website](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiactionsheet), It is clearly said you should use [UIAlertController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uialertcontroller)